# pattern matching with functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've noticed the following peculiarity in Haskell:

```
 data Tree a = Empty  | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

leaf:: a->Tree a
leaf x = Branch x Empty Empty


findNumL:: Tree a->Integer
findNumL (Empty) = 0
findNumL (Branch x Empty Empty) = 1
findNumL (Branch x left right) = (findNumL left) + (findNumL right)
```

This is code will run perfectly fine, and it will return the number of leaves in a binary tree. However, if one tries to call the function `leaf x` instead of `Branch x Empty Empty`, the pattern recognition breaks down, making the definition of `leaf x` much less useful than it could be. Is there a way to circumvent this issue and use the `leaf` in pattern matching?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, probably I don't understand the question.  This one works fine `findNumL $ Branch "root" (leaf "left") (leaf "right")` and so does this `findNumL $ leaf "root"`

Comment: @HenriMenke My apologies. I mean in the function definition, if I try `findNumL (leaf x) = 1` in the second line of the function definition, the code will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the language extension [`PatternSynonyms`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms)

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

data Tree a = Empty  | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
pattern Leaf a = Branch a Empty Empty

findNumL:: Tree a->Integer
findNumL (Empty) = 0
findNumL (Leaf x) = 1
findNumL (Branch x left right) = (findNumL left) + (findNumL right)
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/YAlxEq)

Comment: does this still keep `Leaf` as a function `a->Tree`?

Comment: @AndresMejia No, but you don't need it anymore.  You can just use `Leaf "x"` instead of `leaf "x"`.

Comment: I'm also still getting an error: "data constructor not in scope"

Comment: @AndresMejia Does this happen with the exact example I showed on ideone? https://ideone.com/YAlxEq

Comment: yes, I just copy pasted and loaded it, I got the same error.

Comment: @AndresMejia What's your version of GHC?  I have a relatively ancient version from 2015 (7.10.3) and for me it works.

Comment: winGHCI that came with Haskell platform 8.2.2 for windows. Hm, that is indeed strange.

Comment: @AndresMejia I downloaded Haskell Platform 8.2.2 for Linux quickly and I don't have any problem.  Here is my command line log https://hastebin.com/raw/udezasohep

Comment: @AndresMejia if you are using GHCI interactively rather than compiling with GHC you may need to `:set -XPatternSynonyms`